# Quais as principais diferenças entre REACTJS e Handlerbars?

Tags: node.js, react, handlebars.js

Estou iniciando em desenvolvimento web agora, aprendi a desenvolver uma aplicação simples na WEB.
Estou usando handlebars como minha view engine, porém gostaria de saber a diferença entre o reactjs e o handlebars. Eu pesquisei, li sobre os dois, porém não consegui visualizar realmente uma aplicação, gostaria de aplicar React em um projeto que estou fazendo.
Poderiam me ajudar com exeplos? O ReactJS é diferente do handlebars certo? É possivel utilizar o handlerbars + o ReactJS em um projeto?

Obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beleza Vinícius? para essa sua dúvida recomendo visualizar a diferença mais a fundo de ambos nesse link: https://stackshare.io/stackups/handlebars-vs-react

Handlebars.js é menos utilizado que o React.js mas não quer dizer que seja inferior ou pior por ser uma linguagem para templates enquanto que o React é mais uma biblioteca para interfaces como mostrado nesse artigo acima. Não seria bom misturar ambos pois o próprio React já possui vários módulos de template, mas vai de cada um.

Espero ter ajudado, Abraço.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposata Matheus, eu agradeço sua paciência e tempo em responder minha pergunta, era exatamente isso que estava precisando saber!!